# Approach to hide/show Backbone model views

Tags: backbone.js

Help me to find best approach for managing Backbone views.

For example I have a collection of views `MyCollectionView` which consists of `MyModelView` - views of each model in the collection.

And what if I want to hide/show some models on the page?

Now I am following this way:

- Use `collection.each` for every `model`
- Inside of loop I call model function `filter` with some params
- In this function I check model properties and call `model.trigger 'hide'` or `model.trigger 'show'`
- And finally in the `model view` I use `this.model.bind 'hide', this.hide, this` where actually I use `.hide()` or `.show()`

This way seems me awful... Why do I need to do this long chain of functions and events. Does any simplest approach exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models shouldn't be telling views what they should do - they are supposed to represent data and shouldn't take part in controlling the application - so no wonders it feels wrong to you :)

The more elegant way would be to add a filter method to the MyCollectionView which would use underscore methods to filter the views you want to show/hide and do its job of well... doing that - picking which models should be shown. Then having hte array of matches just call a method for rendering the list and pass your array of models to it so it can render the views for matching models.

From my experience of creating such filters I can tell you that it might be much more efficient for longer lists to remove whole list do filtering on collection level and render again only the views which are matching the filter query. jQuery hide/show can be a bit taxing - though it's a concern you will have only with large amount of data/views.

Also! Take advantage of the underscore methods bound to the collection - you don't need to do `collection.each(...` you can just do

```
var matches = collection.filter(function(model) { 
    return /*matching condition*/;
});
```

(Also remember to use documentFragment when rendering lists and appending to the DOM pre-generated list of views rather then appending them one by one)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have some additional questions.. Why does all logic should be inside of view? I have a lot of statements for filtering. Can I delegate all of them to model? And inside of view filter action use only `return model.filter(conditions)`. And after that I need to call my render function.
Rendering of new view is interestion approach :)

Comment: Moving the filtering method to the collection class definition makes sense as well. But because it's a helper to retrieve a subset of data. Models and Collections are supposed to store data, should be aware of validity of the data etc. but they shouldn't be manipulating it or changing as this is a role of a structure controlling the flow of application - in Backbone view is taking this role.

Comment: As an example of using filtering as a view method rather then collection I can give you you one of mine uses when once I had a special ListView class which was taking care of rendering lists (using documentFragment I mentioned up there) without being aware of the item view or type and structure of a collection - as an option you were able to pass item view factory method, filtering conditions and the view was deciding what it should display based on filter set by the user and took care of picking the right models from the collection to create views for and render